# Pullout Force of Screw from Epoxy

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials

I would like to estimate the pullout force required to pull a screw out of epoxy. Mine is an unusual situation where I want the joint to fail to protect other parts of the assembly; that is, it is a sacrificial joint. The plan would be to select the screw length so that the force required to overpower the screw/epoxy joint is less than the force that would damage other components.

I have been able to find parameters and equations to allow me to estimate the pullout force for a wood/epoxy joint and for a joint where a steel pin is embedded in epoxy, but I have not had success with an estimate for a screw set in epoxy.

Can someone point me toward a source that would address this?

Thank you.

Edit #1:
I thinking the pullout force for the sacrificial joint should be approximately 100 to 200 pounds. The component that would fail next is estimated to fail at about 400 pounds.

Edit #2:
I was hoping to avoid getting into the details of the assembly and instead find a way to evaluate the screw/epoxy joint connection. But here are some more details of the assembly. The sacrificial joint is a repair of the prior sacrificial joint that failed as designed. Initially, a screw penetrated a fiberglass covering on a boat and was threaded into a wood core below the fiberglass. The hole in the fiberglass was larger than the screw diameter, thus preventing damage to the fiberglass should the forces acting on the screw risk damage to the fiberglass. Now I wish to replace the screw, but of course the wood core is stripped. There was also a small amount of soft wood in the core, around the perimeter of the screw hole that had to be removed. I considered filling the hole with either a wood dowel or packing it with slivers of wood. However, I believe the end-grain of the dowel will provide to low a pullout force and calculating the pullout force of the wood slivers is not practical.

My thinking is to use epoxy to fill the hole, and to then use a shorter screw to adjust the pullout force to less than the pullout force of the wood/epoxy joint (which I estimate to be in excess of 400 lbs). If this new epoxy plug were to pull out, it would damage the fiberglass above it. Epoxy also has the benefit of providing a watertight seal so that no further damage occurs to the wood core. Further, should the joint be sacrificed again in the future, the repair would be trivial. So, using this approach, I would need to be able to calculate the pullout force of the screw/epoxy joint. Hence the motivation for my post.

I'm sorry for all of the details, but I really appreciate your interest in this problem. Thank you.

Comment: How do you guarantee the epoxy will have the same strength? Same identical mix?

Comment: A possible solution is a shear bolt.

Comment: I'm not familiar with shear bolts. Are they designed to fail only in shear, not axially?

Comment: With regard to the epoxy strength, I don't have a sense at all for how much the strength varies from one batch to the next. Is there a high percentage difference?

Comment: Use a bracket to orient the shear bolt...

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing the circumstances. For instance, on my old Catalina 38, I have 30,000 pound rated hardware attached the the cockpit coaming which is about 1/8 thick polyester FRP. Not even a spidercrack after 40 years. My fishing line is good for 1000 pounds. Maybe you should try Velcro, snap studs or kite string. On the epoxy front, bury the screw four diameters and it will snap the screw, but stainless **should not** be potted in epoxy due to crevice corrosion issues. Room temp cure epoxies are prone to softening at modest temps, making for a lousy mechanical fuse.

Comment: Consider pop rivets for a mechanical fuse. If installed with a commercial tool and if they are stainless or monel, they will be fairly predicable and consistent. But I'm not sure even the smallest ones will snap at that small a load.

Answer (score 1):

Epoxy is designed to be stronger than concrete.

So ultimately we will have two failure modes:

1 - If the embedment of the screw in the concrete is not enough to develop the yield limit of the screw the failure will be that a cone of concrete opening up to the surface of the concrete will punch out explosively. The surface area of this cone multiplied by the concrete shear value will be the failure load.

2 - If the screw is embedded long enough to develop the yield limit in the screw, the rupture will be the breaking off of the screw at a point near the surface. Therefore the ultimate strength of the screw is its section area multiplied by its yield or rather its rapture strength.

So we need to know the properties of the concrete and the steel and the embedment length.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Please see my Edit #2 for more details. Thanks.